# How to check Android 12 API level?

Tags: android-studio, android-api-levels, android-12

I am trying to check the android 12 API level using the below code.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
{
     // Do something for Android 12 and above versions 
}
else
{
    // Do something for phones running an SDK before Android 12
}
```

but always execute else part when the run application in the android 12 beta device.
is it another way to check the android 12 beta version?

Answer (score 5):

To also detect Android 12 Beta versions you can use `Build.VERSION.CODENAME` like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S || "S".equals(Build.VERSION.CODENAME)) {
    // Android 12 or Android 12 Beta
}
```

Answer (score 2):

BuildCompat.isAtLeastXX(), XX is your target version.

```
if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastS()) {
  //Checks if the device is running on a pre-release version of Android S or a release version of Android S or newer.
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/os/BuildCompat#isAtLeastS()

Comment: Just a note, isAtLeastS() is now marked deprecated.